# How to manage Angular js dependencies and modularity?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, amd

I am starting a new project from scratch, this project is intended to be a responsive website, which mean performance on mobile devices is top priority. I would like to know some information about how angular:

1. How angular manages its resources and dependencies. are the files loaded in memory each time or they live in the memory during the web browsing. also is the use of RequireJS or AngularAMD a solution for this sort of situation?
2. I encountered a situation where I had a page containing tabbed views. in this situation, is it better to create a different view for each one of these views, or is it better to use the native implementation, where all views live on the same page and are loaded simultaneously? (for this case I saw something about the parallel - state)

Comment: 1. always loaded. 2. there is no better, it depends on what performs better with your content; lots of images: load chunks, all text: load a bunch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are focusing on these things way too early for the development phase of the project.

1. If you start simple, by concatenating all of your files into one and properly minifying and gzipping it on serving, you will spend only 20 minutes setting it up instead of fighting an async module loader. Code wisely and try to put your logic into independent modules from the start (which is a good idea not only for browser loading speed, but for maintainability). Moving to a loader is then something you can focus on where you already have something done.

   Any benchmarks or tests on an empty Hello World app will be irrelevant anyway at the beginning.
2. Parallel states are useful if you need to maintain the context of the state deep into one of the tabs. Click through the [wiki example](http://christopherthielen.github.io/ui-router-extras/example/sticky/index.html#/) to understand it. The feature isn't targeting performance, but capabilities of the router of maintaining multiple state trees.

Comment: i think the same for the module loader, benchmarking won't be objective on a near empty project. as for my second question about separating tabs into modules in my case i need to support mobile devices. are there any limitation for them i need to respect ? memory ? network ...

Comment: That strongly depends on *which* mobile devices. A cheap Android phone, an iPhone 6?  Does the target country have 3G or better or is stuck with EDGE? For network, use Google Chrome Inspector network emulation (https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/device-mode#network-conditions) to see how it will look like. For memory, mobile phones are actually pretty good at rendering pages, but don't load content you won't be displaying most of the time